# Using a lookup column to filter library web part

Tags: lookup-column, web

I want my users to select ID's in a list - those ID's have been contacted that day. The problem is: for future reference, the managers want to go back to that day and easily access all library items associated with those ID's.

In other words: on the dispform.aspx page I want to add a webpart that references to the ID's that the user selected in a LookUp Column.

However, the LookUp column information doesn't allow me to reference the information to the other webpart (because the output is ID;ID;ID;ID;..., and SP fails to see it as multiple ID's, I guess?).

Using a normal input (eg. the user typing the ID's) is not an option.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks! (Been stressing out about this all day...)

Comment: Have you tried creating a Lookup that allows for multiple values? There is a field "Allow multiple values" on the column definition screen. You can create a lookup that refers back to the same list.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. The LookUp Column reproduces multiple values (x; x; x; x) and that's what's causing the filter/web part not to recognize the ID's separately to find the correct library items associated with the ID's...

Comment: Perhaps add a review date along with the multi value lookup column, then they can properly filter by that day, or if they want to find the day that an ID was put forward for review, then look at using a search box type scenario. Anything is possible, just depends on how complex you want the solution.